# Лс сообщения с дискорд ботом

Tags: python, discord.py

Подскажите как можно поделить команды так что бы не которые из них работали только в личной переписке с ботом, а другие только на сервере

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@bot.command()
async def dm_or_guild_message(ctx: commands.Context):
    if not ctx.guild:
        await ctx.author.send('dm message')
    else:
        await ctx.send('guild message')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: у меня одновременно, и плюс и минус этому человеку))